# Will D-Wave's quantum computers ruin classical encryption?

Tags: encryption, quantum-cryptography

D-Wave has commercially available 512-qbit quantum computers now.  A lot of [big names](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/small-business/sb-tools/small-business-briefing/quantum-computing-firm-d-wave-lands-30-million/article4591920/) are taking it seriously.  Google, NASA, and USRA have joined forces to [start a quantum AI lab](http://googleresearch.blogspot.ca/2013/05/launching-quantum-artificial.html).

How far are we from destroying classical encryption?  Perhaps a more direct question, what will it take for my bitcoins to be in danger of a quantum brute force attack?

EDIT: I posted this question after reading a [similar one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/436/now-that-quantum-computers-have-been-out-for-a-while-has-rsa-been-cracked), but felt that it was relevant since the other question is 2 years old now and DWave seems to have made new developments (major increases in qubit depth, new interests).
The comment below mentions that DWaves machines aren't crypto-breaking capable, and also that QC is only effective against asymetric encryption (the bitcoin kind!).  I wonder if someone can expand on these points...

Comment: 1) D-Wave's QC isn't of the crypto cracking variety. It's unclear if it's a QC at all 2) There is plenty of classical crypto that survives QCs. Only the popular asymmetric schemes get broken by QCs. Symmetric crypto and some unpopular asymmetric schemes survive.

Comment: See Scott Aaronson's blog to see the latest info on D-Wave. Apparently D-Wave has NOT demonstrated any real quantum computing yet.