# Why can't current quantum computers break RSA?

Tags: encryption, attack, quantum-cryptography

We have quantum computers and we also have Shor's algorithm. So:

1. Why isn't RSA cracked yet?
2. What are the current quantum computers lacking?

Comment: Who said it isn't cracked? If someone bothered to do through the effort of cracking it with the intent to misuse it, why would such a person ever announce that? It would be very, very dangerous to announce such a thing even if you did it without any malicious intent whatsoever.

Comment: To break RSA-2048 you need about 4000 perfect qubits. I think the best quantum computers are around 5 bits at the moment.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's exactly what I needed to know! Do you have any sources for that? Isn't D-Wave operating at 128-qubits? And about 1.5n qubits would be required for RSA-2048 (see paper by Zalka) with n being the amount of digits. So that'd be 926 qubits.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem D-Wave computers are incapable of running Shor's algorithm, so they can't attack RSA. They're limited to one particular optimization problem.

Comment: Also see: [*"Now that quantum computers have been out for a while, has RSA been cracked?"*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/436/23623)