# Are analog quantum computers a threat to RSA and DLP?

Tags: cryptanalysis, discrete-logarithm, factoring

[We already know that D-WAVE's "quantum computers" can't really run the Shor's algorithm, because the way they're built doesn't qualify them as universal quantum computers.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/436/23623)

Now researchers actually found out that so-called analog quantum computers can be scaled much better and quicker (for now) than normal, digital ones. [(relevant paper)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v534/n7606/full/nature17658.html)

Now for the important question:
**Can analog quantum computers run any (currently known) algorithm, dangerous to modern cryptography?**

Comment: Who knows, there was a a time where shor's algorithm didn't exist yet, so there might be an algorithm out there that need to be discovered.

Comment: To my knowledge, existing quantum computers (such as D-Wave) can only solve optimization problems, doing quantum annealing. This is not known to be dangerous for modern cryptography, however this topic of research is very recent, so we might find out some new applications in a close futur

Comment: Not duplicates of the _question_, per se, but there are other questions with answers that cover this one: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59796 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59823