# Quantum computers and elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography

I know, that quantum computers can theoretically break the discrete logarithm problem using the shor algorithm. The problem with quantum computers is not the time, but the space ( the needed qubits ). My question is: Can elliptic curve cryptographie be adjusted so that they are secure against quantum computers? ( e.g. longer key length )

Comment: Does this answer to your question [How effective is quantum computing against elliptic curve cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59770/18298)

Comment: Related to your question: [Supersingular isogeny key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange).

Comment: "The problem with quantum computers is not the time, but the space ( the needed qubits )" - actually, as we don't have a real quantum computer (a cryptographically relevant one) in front of us, we don't know what would be its most critical constraints - it may be the number of qubits, it may be a bound on the circuit depth, it may be limitations on moving the qubits around...

Comment: Main problem with Quantum Computers has been the measuring of the Qbit-state, typically 30% failure for a set of 14Qbits and this grows exponentially with the set size. Guess, for a long time, security will rely on the dimension of combinatorial problems, meaning your question is less ECC specific. Guess finally we'll have a performance race ECC vs RSA with long keys and AES certainly dead.